# Calculate the number of order $p$ elements in a group (using Sylow)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I'm having trouble understanding how to calculate the number of elements of order $p$ (being $p$ prime number) in a group $G$ so that
$$|G|=p^a\cdot m,$$
being $a\in\mathbb{N}$, $a\geq 1$, and $p\nmid m$. I need this for problems of the form: "*Prove that there aren't simple groups of order $x$*" and so. For these, I first calculate the minimum number of Sylow p-subgroups of $G$ to verify that $G$ is simple (that's the smallest number possible greater than $1$). I do that for every prime factor in $G$, and calculate the number of elements of each prime order (This is the operation I don't know), and if I've done everything right, the sum of all them plus $1$ (the neutral element) must be greater that $|G|$, thus a contradiction.

What is the "formula" for calculating these number of elements of each prime order $p$ in $G$ (knowing |G| and the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups)?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Example:

> Prove that groups of order $132$ aren't simple.

For this problem, I know that $132=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 11$, and, if it's not simple, then the minimum nomber of Sylow subgroups are $n_11=12$, $n_3=4$ and $n_2=3$. So I know there are $12\cdot (11-1)=120$ elements of order $11$ and $4\cdot (3-1)=8$ elements of order 3. My book then states that there are at least $4$ elements of order $4$ (but I don't know why is this, the exponent of $2$ is $2$ and I don't know how to calculate the minimum number of elements of order $2$). Finally he sees that
$$120+8+4+1=133>132$$
so $G$ is not simple.

My question is: why a minimum of $4$ order $2$ elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is possible only when the exponent $a=1$. In which case the $p$-Sylow subgroups will be cyclic of order $p$ and there can't be any overlap between the $p$-Sylow subgroups other than the identity element i.e. $P_i \cap P_j =\{e\}$ because the cardinality of the intersection of those two subgroups $|P_i \cap P_j|$ should divide $p=|P_i|=|P_j|$. In general if $a>1$ there can be overlap between the subgroups.

A good exercise for the above technique the following problem

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $pqr$ where $p,q,r$ are distint primes. Show that $G$ cannot be simple

> $\mathbf{Hint}$: Show that there is always a normal $p$ or $q$ or $r$ Sylow subgroup

Comment: Thanks for your comment! And can I find a minimum number of order $p$ elements for $a>1$? (Just enough to pove that the group ccan't be simple)

Comment: I'll put an example exercise in my question to illustrate my point, give it a look when edited please.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso I think that is also not easy to calculate just from Sylow's theorems. You have to use some other techniques. For example consider a non abliean group of order $12=2^2 3$. We can't just conclude from this because when the group is $A_4$ there are $4$ order $2$ elements because the $2$-Sylow subgroup is $\mathbf{Z/2Z}$ but there is a group of order $12$ the $2$-Sylow subroup is $\mathbf{Z/2Z}$

Comment: In my example (I got it from an exercises book), do you know why is it that there are at least $4$ order $2$ elements? Thanks for your support.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso I'm reading it. I'll let you know once I figure it out.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso Let $P_1,P_2,P_3$ be those $2$-Sylow subgroups. By the classification of groups of order $2^2$ there are only two isomorphism classes $\mathbb{Z/2Z \times Z/2Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z/2^2Z}$. Hence all of them are of the same type by Sylow's theorem. Now look at the generators $P_1$ they are two in number (irrespective of the isomorphism). If both of them are in $P_2$ then $P_1=P_2$. Hence $P_2$ contains a different generator other than the two we have. So we have at least 3 distinct elements now. Similarly you can argue to produce a 4th distinct element.

Comment: But $\mathbb{Z}/2^2\mathbb{Z}$ has just one generator right? (the element $\bar 1$) And, imagine $P_1$ generators are $a,b$. Then, we get that a possible $P_2$ has generators  $a,c$. If our $P_3$ has as generators $b,c$, it's different from both $P_1, P_2$ and we just have $3$ elements of order $2$, not $4$. Sorry if I'm saying dumb things due to my misunderstanding, thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso $\overline{3}$ is also a generator.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso I'm adding the extra details to the second to last comment I wrote. Let's split case wise. Suppose $P_1 \cong P_2 \cong P_3\cong \mathbb{Z/2Z}^2$ then $|P_1 \cap P_2 |=2 $ or $ 1$. So in either case there are $4$ distinct elements(2 from $P_1$ and 2 from $P_2$) in total in $P_1$ and $P_2$ other than those in $P_1\cap P_2$. Suppose $P_1 \cong \mathbb{Z/4Z}$. Again $|P_1 \cap P_2|=1$ or $2$. But in $Z/4Z$ there is only one element of order $2$. So the order 4 elements are all distinct which are 4 in number, 2 from each $P_1$ and $P_2$. Is it clear now?